# Please help me change these sentences using 不止

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, mandarin, sentence

I'm not sure if what I changed below was correct or not.

1. 我看陳太太那麼老，恐怕不會只有70歲吧?

-> 我看陳太太那麼老，恐怕不止70歲吧？

2. 愛闖紅燈的，並不是只有騎摩托車的，開車的也一樣。

-> 愛闖紅燈的，不止是騎摩托車的，開車的也一樣。

3. 王小姐家不但她能幹，她兩個姐姐也是女強人。

-> 王小姐家不止她能幹，她兩個姐姐也是女強人。

4. 我們的產品除了內銷以外，還外銷。

-> 我們的產品不止是內銷，還外銷。

Comment: According to the following links ([link1](http://www.hwjyw.com/zhwh/content/2021/01/11/36246.shtml),[link2](http://www.xinhuanet.com/politics/2016-02/20/c_128735530.htm),[link3](http://xh.5156edu.com/page/z4380m9037j20881.html)), only the first sentence should use 不止. The others should use 不只.

Answer (score 3):

- 不只A，B：not only A but also B
- 不止A：Not limited to A
- A不止：A Non-stoppablely

Examples

- 恐怕不止70歲吧？: not limited to 70 years old
- 不只是騎摩托車的，開車的也一樣: not only motorcyclers but also car drivers
- 不只她能幹，她兩個姐姐也是: not only her but also her sisters
- 不只是內銷，還外銷: not only domestic markets but also exports
- 流血不止: bleeding non-stoppablely

Comment: 不止 also describe  "uncontrollably" . e.g. 痛哭不止, 狂笑不止, 疼癢不止

Answer (score 0):

不止 or 不只?

不止 = 不止于这么多, 不限于这个数量. (not only this much of the amount).

不只 = 不只是这件事情, 不仅仅是这个东西. (not only this one but also that one).

For example:

她看上去很老，恐怕不止70歲吧？（恐怕不会小于70歲吧）

闖紅燈的，不只是騎摩托車的，还有開車的。

王小姐家不是只有她能幹，她的兩個姐姐也是女強人。

我們的產品不仅仅是內銷，還有外銷。

In any case try to use longer words (不小于, 不只有) than just use (不止, 不只) in either written or spocken language.